# Microsoft Office 365 Apps Usage

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to collate information corresponding to Microsoft 365 Apps Usage of our employees as shown in some reports on Admin Portal(admin.microsoft.com). We are facing some challenges in getting report data corresponding to these in our code.

I need following information for integration in our web application:

1. Do we have any Graph API or PowerShell cmdlet(not deprecated) exposed which can be integrated in our code to get Microsoft Apps Usage Data(like ProPlusUsageUserDetail excel data downloaded from admin portal)?
2. Can we get Version Details of Microsoft 365 Apps and Services being used by users?

We have already used graph api GetOffice365ActiveUserDetail (adding link below for reference) which give usage for only Microsoft Services and not Apps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getoffice365activeuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

We need same kind of information for Microsoft 365 Apps (Word, Excel, PowerPoint etc.)as well .

Comment: You can try portal.office.com and check the reports to see if you have related report is available apart from that, at this point i am not aware such information you can request from Microsoft Graph APIs. Consider raising a feature request in User voice, so that Microsoft can consider it. Here's the link for it.https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=report

Answer (score 0):

You can try portal.office.com and check the reports to see if you have related report is available apart from that, at this point i am not aware such information you can request from Microsoft Graph APIs. Consider raising a feature request in User voice, so that Microsoft can consider it. Here's the link for it https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=report